# @BeforeAll not working in SOME files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit5

I want to convert from JUnit 4 to 5 in Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.3a. I thought adding the Jupiter library would be sufficient: libraries, build path, etc. However, `@BeforeAll`, `@AfterAll`, `@BeforeEach`, and `@AfterEach` do not get executed, but the @Test methods do--but of course they fail without the proper setup.

Interestingly, I can create a file using the new Junit 5 Jupiter wizard, and that test file works. I copy and paste the JUnit 5 annotations from the new file to my existing file, and it still doesn't work. I am beginning to wonder if Eclipse has some configuration info somewhere behind the scenes of which I am unaware.

Comment: Please show your code, imports included. The most common reason is, you’re using the wrong @Test annotation.

Comment: I had junit 4 and 5 mixed. I ended up using `@BeforeClass/ @AfterClass` instead for junit 4.

Comment: The possible reason is that Junit 5 is not setup properly or you are importing the wrong @Test annotation from the Junit 4

Answer (score 79):

I was using

```
import org.junit.Test;
```

instead of

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

which triggered the JUnit 5 runner to think it was working with a JUnit 4 file. 
Easy solution, but hard to find since no errors messages were generated, and the file still ran. Also made more mystifying because "Organize Imports" added the JUnit 4 `Test` class, and not the jupiter `Test` class.

Comment: Which crazy fool voted this answer down? It was exactly my problem. If junit4 sneaks into your classpath through some maven dependency, this is exactly what happens.

Comment: You've gained Legendary Status for me today.

Comment: I was using Junit4 annotation along with some Junit5 annotations. Removed Junit4 imports fixed my problem

Comment: Junit 4 and 5 shouldn't be allowed to coexist like that!

Answer (score 17):

Try to change it to `static`.
The `@BeforeAll` method must be `static` unless the test class is annotated with `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`.

Comment: This should be the approved answer. I followed other advice from this post and others about @Test and adding the surefire plugin. Even after verifying I had all the correct plugins and dependencies, I still had the problem.

Comment: terrible error message "No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'." This one solved for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are converting an individual test class from JUnit 4 to JUnit Jupiter, chances are that you ran the test class previously in Eclipse.

If that's the case, Eclipse already has a saved *Run Configuration* for that test class with the version of JUnit set to 4.

To tell Eclipse to run the same test class now as a JUnit Jupiter test class, you'll need to edit the run configuration for that test class. Select "Run Configurations..." from the "Run" menu. Then change the "Test runner" from "JUnit 4" to "JUnit 5. Then click the "Run" button.

FYI: this is also documented in the [Eclipse JUnit 5 documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7.1a/#junit-5-support). Search for the *Note* starting with "If you are using an Eclipse workspace where you were running".

Hope this helps!